# fs.createWriteStream alternatives for whole website?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there an alternative to `fs.createWriteStream` so that it will check a whole page instead of files/directories on a website? since this: `fs.createWriteStream('https://discordapp.com/channels/000/000', function(err, data) {` returns that no directory or file is found but I would like to be able to search for words on the page.

```
https.get('https://discordapp.com/channels/000/000', function (err, data) {
```

returns:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/Discord_bots/my-bot/index.js:214
            if (err) throw err;
                     ^
[object Object]
```

Comment: Are you ok with external libraries for this?Maybe you should take a look at phantomJS?

Comment: I just installed it however I can not get it to work properly, I will create a new question, thank you :)